# How to find substrings between substrings within a python string?

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

Let the string be `"AAAGQWERTYUIOPAGCTHJKLAAAGZXCVBNMAGCT"`. I want to find the strings between AAAG and AGCT.

I would like the output to be `["QWERTYUIOP","ZXCVBNM"]`, i.e. a list of strings.

How can I use regex or similar techniques to do this?

I tried this

```
def find_distances_between_motifs(positions1, positions2, motif_length1):
diff1 = []
diff2 = []
pos2 = 0
flag = 0
for pos1 in range(len(positions1)):
    if pos2 >= len(positions2):
        break
    if flag == 1:
        flag = 0
        pos1 -= 1
    if positions2[pos2] - positions1[pos1] > 30:
        diff1.append(NaN)
        diff2.append(NaN)
        continue
    elif positions2[pos2] - positions1[pos1] < 1:
        pos2 += 1
        diff2.append(NaN)
        flag = 1
    elif pos1 < len(positions1) - 1 and positions1[pos1+1] > positions2[pos2]:
        diff1.append(positions[pos2] - positions[pos1] - motif_length1)
        diff2.append(pos2)
        pos2 += 1
    else:
        continue
return diff1, diff2
```

I wanted to return two arrays - one with location of length of sequences in between motifs and second with the location of second motif which will give the previous distances.

Comment: Should not the output be `["QWERTYUIOP","HJKL","ZXCVBNM"]`?

Comment: No! I want the sequence between first and second substring, not between the second and first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Regex.  `re.findall` with Lookbehind & Lookahead

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "AAAGQWERTYUIOPAGCTHJKLAAAGZXCVBNMAGCT"
print( re.findall(r"(?<=AAAG).*?(?=AGCT)", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['QWERTYUIOP', 'ZXCVBNM']
```

Comment: The OP also had this poorly stated requirement: "I wanted to return two arrays - one with location of length of sequences in between motifs and second with the location of second motif which will give the previous distances."  Whatever it is he needs could probably be well served by changing `re.findall` to `re.finditer` which returns `Match` objects.  Then with Match `m`, `m.group(0)` gives the matched string, and `m.start()` and `m.end()` give the indices of the match. With those indices everything else can be calculated.

Comment: This requirement was not necessary. I was trying things to find sequences. I can work with just the sequences.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regex expression, then I have made a code. Its a bit complex but if you look carefully into it then you will understand.

```
def addd(llist,word,word2):
    xx1 = sum([[i, word] for i in llist], [])[:-1]
    try:iii = xx1.index(word2);del xx1[iii]
    except:pass
    return xx1
a,output = addd("AAAGQWERTYUIOPAGCTHJKLAAAGZXCVBNMAGCT".split("AAAG"),"St4rT",""),[]
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    if "AGCT" in x:
        output.append(addd(x.split("AGCT"),"3nD.",""))
    else:output.append(x)
total = []
for i in output:
    if isinstance(i,list):total+=i
    elif isinstance(i,str):total.append(i)
output,typ = [],0
for x,i in enumerate(total):
    if typ == 0 and i == "St4rT":
        try:output.append(total[x+1]);typ = 1
        except:pass
    elif typ == 1 and i == "3nD.":typ = 0
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['QWERTYUIOP', 'ZXCVBNM']
```